# MLKit pose detection

Tags: google-mlkit

cloned an APP from github that is supposed to take a video and estimate a person's pose using MLKIT.
The thing is the app I think fills up the memory buffers and crashes itself and I don't know how to get a result, if anyone could give me some tips on how to avoid this crash on Kotlin and thank you.

```
Log.d("LOG:", "Here")

    val bm = mTextureView.bitmap

    if (bm != null) {
        Log.d("LOG:", "not null")
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50,out)

        val inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream( ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray())), 0)
        poseDetector.process(inputImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener { pose ->
                if (parentLayout.childCount > 4) parentLayout.removeViewAt(4)
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bm)
                if (pose.allPoseLandmarks.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val draw = Draw(applicationContext, pose)
                    parentLayout.addView(draw)
                    var content : String = ""
                    pose.allPoseLandmarks.forEach {
                        content = content + (it.position3D.x) + (",") + (it.position3D.y) + (",") + (it.position3D.z) + (",") + (it.inFrameLikelihood) + (",")
                    }
                    println(content)
                    content += "\n"
                    fileOut.appendText(content)
                Log.d("LOG:", "Success")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { Log.d("LOG:", "Failure") }
    } else Log.d("LOG:", "null")
```

Comment: Maybe use the Android Studio profiler to understand more about what are the objects causing the memory issue: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Answer (score 0):

The app may be crashing because the variable **mTextureView** is null. The bitmap property is called on it, but it is not initialized.

It is possible that **mTextureView** is not being initialized before it is used in the code, or it is not being correctly passed to this function. You should check if **mTextureView** is initialized or not, if not, you should initialize it before using it in the code.

Another possible reason is that the variable 'out' is not initialized, it might be causing the crash.

It's also possible that there is an issue with the **ByteArrayInputStream** or **BitmapFactory.decodeStream** calls, which could be causing a crash if the input data is invalid or in an unexpected format.

It would be helpful to check the logcat for the exact error message when the app crashes. It would give more information about the cause of the crash.

It would be best to check the initialization of the variables and make sure that they are not null before using them in the code.

Comment: I recycled the bitmaps after usage and that fixed the problem.
Thank you sir